# with ouath.io how to create the OAuth.create to use as on the callback

Tags: facebook, authentication, twitter, oauth

With oauth.io how to make a OAuth.create for twitter

for facebook it is

```
        facebook_auth = OAuth.create("facebook", { oauth_token: "token_here" }, {
            "url": "https://graph.facebook.com",
            "cors": true,
            "query": {
                "access_token": "token_here"
            }
        });
```

that way you can use it on different parts of your website not just the callback after sign in.

```
         facebook_auth.get('/me?fields=name,email').done(function (data) {

 });
```

otherwise you're stuck only with the callback:

```
   OAuth.callback('facebook', function (err, result) {
         result.get('/me?fields=name,email').done(function (data) {

 });

});
```

this is link to their documentation:
https://oauth.io/docs/api

Answer (score 2):

For twitter, it's the same syntaxe than with facebook

```
var twitterTokens
OAuth.popup('twitter', function(err, res){
    twitterTokens = res
})

//then elsewhere
function createTwitter() {
    return OAuth.create('twitter', twitterTokens)
}
var twitter = createTwitter()
twitter.get(....)
```

The 3rd parameter is optional